# Resources available locally but "No such file or directory" when packaged and deployed with Poetry

Tags: python, resource-files

I use paths defined as constants, e.g. `TF_CONSTS = 'consts/tf_keras_param_config.json'` and they work fine during development.

However, when the package is built with Poetry (i.e. `poetry build --format sdist`) and deployed, these references become invalid even though the JSON files are copied along with the Python scripts:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'some_package/consts/tf_keras_param_config.json'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths work fine during development, but - when the code is packaged and then installed - they must be translated to absolute ones and these must be determined dynamically (they depend on the location of the installed package):

```
import pkg_resources

# necessary for the path to resolve properly when package is installed
TF_CONSTS = pkg_resources.resource_filename("some_package", "consts/tf_keras_param_config.json")
```

---

Consider also [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources):

> This module provides functionality similar to [`pkg_resources` Basic Resource Access](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) without the performance overhead of that package. This makes reading resources included in packages easier, with more stable and consistent semantics.